# Java List<Map<String, Long>> sum of group by of map key

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a: `List<Map<String, Long>> items = new ArrayList<>();`

I would like to get a Map in which the key is grouped by, and the value is the sum.

Example: List

- Item 0

  - foo -> 1
  - bar -> 2
- Item 1

  - foo -> 4
  - bar -> 3

Result: Map

- foo -> 5
- bar -> 5

I know how to do this the "long" way, but was trying to discover a lambda/streaming/groupby approach using the java 8 features.  any thoughts?

Comment: Might just be a typo, but could you restate what you want the key to be grouped by, because you say "...in which the key is grouped by, ...".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `groupingBy` collector:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.summingLong;

items.stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, summingLong(Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

Or you can use `toMap`:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

items.stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Long::sum));
```

Comment: Hey @Misha, could you add in the import statements? I can't get the method references to compile.

Comment: I'm getting a compiler error on the method reference for `getValue`. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using eclipse perchance?

Comment: Eclipse has issues with type inference (or at least older versions used to).  But i just tried it with eclipse Mars and it compiles fine.

Comment: Yep, that makes perfect sense. I'm using Luna here at home. But at work, I'm using Mars. Good call.

Comment: Note that `summingLong` solution might work faster when there are many keys merged into one as it reduces boxing.

Comment: @TagirValeev right, although `toMap` will be faster if there are few repeating keys

Comment: @Misha thank you for taking the time to respond I gave it a try and it worked!  I had a feeling I needed to use .flatMap, but I was getting stuck on pulling out the parts for the collectors.groupingBy.  Much appreciated!