# how to merge a collection of Maps using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a collection of maps:

```
Collection<Map<String,Double>> myCol = table.values();
```

I would like to transform this into a Map

```
Map<String, Double>
```

such that, for a matching key, values are summed up. Using a for loop, it is rather simple:

```
Map<String, Double> outMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Map<String, Double> map : myCol) {
    outMap =  mergeMaps(outMap, map);
}
```

and `mergeMaps()` is defined as

```
mergeMaps(Map<String, Double> m1, Map<String, Double> m2){    
    Map<String, Double> outMap = new TreeMap<>(m1);
    m2.forEach((k,v) -> outMap.merge(k,v,Double::sum)); /*sum values if key exists*/
    return outMap;
}
```

However, I would like to use streams to get a map from collection. I have tried as follows:

```
Map<String, Double> outMap = new HashMap<>();    
myCol.stream().forEach(e-> outMap.putAll(mergeMaps(outMap,e)));
return outMap;
```

This works without a problem. However, can I still improve it? I mean, how can I use collectors in it?

Comment: probably, somewhat similar --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325389/java-listmapstring-long-sum-of-group-by-of-map-key

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From your input, you can fetch the stream of maps and then flatmap it to have a `Stream<Map.Entry<String, Double>>`. From there, you collect them into a new map, specifying that you want to sum the values mapped to the same key.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.summingDouble;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

....

Map<String, Double> outMap = 
    myCol.stream()
         .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
         .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Double::sum));
```

Alternatively, you can use `groupingBy` instead of `toMap`:

```
.collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, summingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

Comment: Could you explain the benefits and drawbacks of `toMap` and `groupingBy`? Are there fundamental differences in performance? From a readability point of view, I'd prefer the `groupingBy` approach, but that is just my opinion.

Comment: @MalteHartwig Concerning this use case, I don't expect much performance difference (again only proper measurements will tell the truth). The advantage with `groupingBy` is that you can chain downstream collectors if you need more complex reductions and as you said it's more expressive.

Answer (score 2):

```
 myCol.stream()
        .flatMap(x -> x.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Entry::getKey, 
                TreeMap::new, 
                Collectors.summingDouble(Entry::getValue)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the other proposed solutions show that a pure stream solution is short, but if you wanted to use your existing mergeFunction (because in other cases it is more complex for example), you could just hand it over to `Stream.reduce`:

```
Optional<Map<String, Double>> outMap = myCol.stream().reduce((m1, m2) -> mergeMaps(m1, m2));
```

Your initial approach with the forEach is pretty much a streamyfied for loop and violates the concept of functions having no side effects. The reduce (or the above collects) handles all the data merging internally, without changing the input collection.

Comment: Hi! There's nothing wrong with functions having side-effects. They are discouraged when used in streams, but it's absolutely correct to use them in a `forEach`. On the other side, your solution with `reduce` creates a new map every step, which might not be the best.

Comment: Now that I look closer into it, the original question has the same problem: a new, intermediate map is being created for every pair of maps being merged.

Comment: True, but you could prevent that by using the `reduce` with identity, and the `merge` method uses the first map as result. Also has the advantage of a guaranteed return value.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Maybe the part about side effects came across a bit harsh. I meant to say that the initial approach didn't really take much advantage of streams yet. Creating a stream of a collection only to call forEach immediately causes unnecessary overhead and does not take advantage of the rest of the stream API.

Answer (score 1):

With streams:

```
Map<String, Double> outMap = myCol.stream()
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,   // key of the result map
        Map.Entry::getValue, // value of the result map
        Double::sum,         // how to merge values for equal keys
        TreeMap::new));      // the type of map to be created
```

This uses [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) to create the result `TreeMap`.

You can do it without streams, though. I think your version is a little bit complicated, you could refactor it as follows:

```
Map<String, Double> outMap = TreeMap<>();
myCol.forEach(map -> map.forEach((k, v) -> outMap.merge(k, v, Double::sum)));
```

Which is shorter, easy and most readable.