# Two loops for into stream

Tags: java, selenium, for-loop, java-stream

I have some String method with two for and if:

```
public String getCellValue(String stringFirst, int integerFirst) {
    List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='dt']/tbody/tr"));

    int index = 0;
    WebElement dataCell = null;

    for (WebElement row : tableRows) {
        index++;

        List<WebElement> tableCells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

        for (WebElement cell : tableCells) {

            if (getTextFromElement(cell).equals(stringFirst)) {

                dataCell = driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//table[@id='dt']/tbody/tr[%s]/td[%s]", index, integerFirst)));
            }
        }
    }

    return getTextFromElement(dataCell);
}
```

And I still try to change this implementation to some stream. Is it possible in this case? I've tried many options, but I have a problem with indexing (index++;) and then with filter in tableCells By.tagname. I think that is it not possible to change that full method to stream, but I don't know. Could you help me with some implementation?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Understanding given data:**

To get all rows:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='dt']/tbody/tr"))
```

To get columns(cells) for a given row:

```
row.findElements(By.tagName("td"))
```

To get the text for a given column(cell):

```
getTextFromElement(cell)
```

Result expected if the text on cell at row index matches given string(stringFirst):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//table[@id='dt']/tbody/tr[%s]/td[%s]", index, integerFirst)))
```

From the requirements, it seems like logic should be around indexes.

**Breakdown of approach:**

Firstly, we need a list of rows. This is exactly the same as before:

```
List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='dt']/tbody/tr"));
```

Now we'll create an IntStream of all indexes.
rangeClosed means ends are inclusive
boxed() is used to convert primitive ints to Integer

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1,tableRows.size()).boxed()
```

```
1,
2,
3,
...
```

For each index idx, create a map with idx as key and columns corresponding to row idx as value:

```
.map(idx -> Map.of(idx, list.get(idx-1).findElements(By.tagName("td"))))
```

```
{1=[cell11, cell12, cell13]},
{2=[cell21, cell22, cell23]},
...
```

Merging all the maps:

```
.flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
```

```
1=[cell11, cell12, cell13],
2=[cell21, cell22, cell23],
...
```

Filter out the values that do not contain cell with text as a given string:
findAny() returns Optional if any value is found(not sure if that is the requirement)

```
.filter(containsCellWithText).findAny()
```

Implementation of the above Predicate:

```
Predicate<Map.Entry> containsCellWithText = (Map.Entry me) -> me.getValue()
                                                                .stream()
                                                                .anyMatch(cell -> getTextFromElement(cell).equals(stringFirst));
```

Now, only desired entries remain. Fetch the result for the corresponding index:

```
.map(me -> driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//table[@id='dt']/tbody/tr[%s]/td[%s]", me.getKey(), integerFirst))))
```

We should have the answer in Optional(if exist). Fetch it or else get an empty string:

```
.orElse("")
```

**Complete answer put together:**

```
List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='dt']/tbody/tr"));
        
Predicate<Map.Entry> containsCellWithText = (Map.Entry me) -> me.getValue()
                                                                .stream()
                                                                .anyMatch(cell -> getTextFromElement(cell).equals(stringFirst));
        
IntStream.rangeClosed(1,tableRows.size())
         .boxed()
         .map(idx -> Map.of(idx, list.get(idx-1).findElements(By.tagName("td"))))
         .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
         .filter(containsCellValue)
         .findAny()
         .map(me -> driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//table[@id='dt']/tbody/tr[%s]/td[%s]", me.getKey(), integerFirst))))
         .orElse("")
```

**Resources:**

- [How to merge stream of maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334245/how-to-merge-a-collection-of-maps-using-streams)
- [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)
- [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html)
- [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

Comment: Please note that some operations like Map.of() works in Java 9 onwards

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you are asking about here, but when you trying to get "tableCells" from each row I'm pretty sure this doesn't do what you expecting.

```
List<WebElement> tableCells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
```

It doesn't actually search `td` elements inside this particular row rather on the entire page.
To get `td`'s inside specific row you have to use this:

```
List<WebElement> tableCells = row.findElements(By.xpath(".//td"));
```